# How can I mount a vintage light fixture?

Tags: lighting

I have a 1920’s flush mount light fixture. It has 2 small holes in the brass housing. I cannot use a mounting bracket, how can I hang this?  The holes are over 7” apart.

Comment: Why is it that you cannot use a mounting bracket? Maybe consider including a photo of the fixture (with a tape measure) so we can see what you see.

Comment: The common mounting brackets might be too short for 7 inches, but I imagine they do have longer ones.  If I knew the code better, might even recommend just getting a piece of metal of the right size and drilling holes where you need them, but not sure if it is allowed by code.  Will need a code expert to say.

Comment: Since code allows you to put a hole in a steel box to mount it to a wall, @crip659, I'd imagine it would allow you to make your own mounting bracket. Just needs to be thick enough material to support the weight of the fixture...